# Fetch SQL records without going through each row

Tags: mysql, vb.net

**Context:**
I have around 50 records of names with their fingerprints saved in a database that will be needed for their daily time-in/time-out using a fingerprint scanner.

**The code:**

```
Dim conn As New MySqlConnection("...database_details")
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand

    Private Sub FetchRecords(sender As Object, e As IZKFPEngXEvents_OnCaptureEvent) Handles ZkFprint.OnCapture
        'fingerprint sample from the scanner, returns a BASE64 format
        Dim fp = e.aTemplate 
    
        Using conn 
            conn.Open()
            cmd = conn.CreateCommand()
            With cmd
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                'fprint stores varchar data type
                .CommandText = "SELECT id,name,reg_fprint FROM tbl_emp"
            End With
            Dim dr as MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            While dr.Read
                'converts the fprint into BASE64
                Dim fpFromDB = ZkFprint.DecodeTemplate1(dr.GetValue(1)) 
    
                'compares fp to fpFromDB; returns true if match otherwise false
                Dim result As = ZkFprint.VerFinger(fpFromDB, fp)
                If result = True Then
                    lbName.Text = dr.GetValue(1)
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Fingerprint not found")
                End If
            End While
        End Using
    End Sub
```

**The problem:**
When I scan a finger to time in/out, the MessageBox.Show("Fingerprint not found") line will trigger X-1 times before my lbName.Text changes to the matching record. This is because dr.Read() reads the first row until I find the record.

**What I want:**
Is there a way for me to get the record without going through each row?

**What I tried:**
I removed the Else statement, which solved my problem but leads me to another problem: it does not provide any feedback if a finger is not registered.

```
If result = True Then
   lbName.Text = dr.GetValue(1)
End If
```

**EDIT:**
Thanks for the inputs, I appreciate it. I also manage to come up with a solution after playing with the code a few times thanks to @Shadow below the commments. I replaced the While Loop with a For Loop and put the data in a DataTable so I can easily go through them. I also used the recordCount as a reference if a record does not exists.

```
Dim fp = e.aTemplate 
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim recordCount As Integer
Using conn 
            conn.Open()
            cmd = conn.CreateCommand()
            With cmd
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                'fprint stores varchar data type
                .CommandText = "SELECT id,name,reg_fprint FROM tbl_emp"
            End With

            Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            da.Fill(dt)

            For recordCount = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                Dim result As = ZkFprint.VerFinger(dt.Rows(recordCount).Item(2).ToString, fp)
                If result = True Then
                    lbName.Text = dt.Rows(recordCount).Item(1).ToString
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next

            If recordCount = dt.Rows.Count Then
                MessageBox.Show("Fingerprint not found")
            End If
    End Using
```

Comment: Unless you can perform the fingerprint comparison in mysql using the where clause, no it is not possible to skip looping though the rows. However, the fingerprint not found message should only be displayed once you loop through all rows and no match was found. So, it should be after the while loop.

Comment: `.CommandText = "SELECT id,name,reg_fprint FROM tbl_emp"  ` can be slower with while loop if the number of records is big

Answer (score 1):

You may consider comparing the column fild while converting to base64

```
Dim conn As New MySqlConnection("...database_details")
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand

    Private Sub FetchRecords(sender As Object, e As IZKFPEngXEvents_OnCaptureEvent) Handles ZkFprint.OnCapture
        'fingerprint sample from the scanner returns a BASE64 format
        Dim fp = e.aTemplate 
    
        Using conn 
            conn.Open()
            cmd = conn.CreateCommand()
            With cmd
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                'fprint stores varchar data type
                .CommandText = "SELECT id,name,reg_fprint FROM tbl_emp WHERE TO_BASE64(reg_fprint)=@reg_fprint"
                .Parameters.Add(New MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@reg_fprint", fp))
            End With
            Dim dr as MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            If dr.Read             
               lbName.Text = dr.GetValue(1)
               lbName.refresh() 'To update label text
            Else
               MessageBox.Show("Fingerprint not found")
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub
```

But again you could change this block

```
If result = True Then
   lbName.Text = dr.GetValue(1)
End If
```

to

```
If result = True Then
   lbName.Text = dr.GetValue(1)
   lbName.Refresh() 'Update the label
End If
```